# Trait method with free parameters

Tags: scala

I am trying to write a repository trait like:

```
trait Repository[E <: Entity] {
  def exists(id: Long): Boolean
  def get(id: Long): E
  def insert(entity: E): Unit
  def delete(entity: E): Unit
}
```

The problem with this code is that an entity can have a composite key that is not a Long, so I have problems fulfilling the trait contract when implementing the repositories.

I have tried to represent the key as an implementation of another trait, but I can't fulfill the contract because of the repository trait cannot handle the specific implementation of each entity.

Can I set the parameters of exists and get to be free? can I specify the type of the functions to depend on the type of key of de entity?

Comment: What about adding another type parameter to `Repository` for `Long`? Or an abstract type alias.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try to represent the composite key as a tuple.

```
trait Repository[E <: Entity, K] {
  def exists(id: K): Boolean
  def get(id: K): E
  def insert(entity: E): Unit
  def delete(entity: E): Unit
}
```

Where an Entity called Thing, whose key was a composite of a String and a Long, would be:

```
class ThingRepository extends Repository[Thing, (String, Long)] {
  def exists(id: (String, Long)): Boolean = ???
  def get(id: (String, Long)): Thing = ???
  def insert(entity: Thing): Unit = ???
  def delete(entity: Thing): Unit = ???
}
```

Comment: This works perfect. I think it would be better, though, if you could delegate the responsibility of the key to the entity (Entity[K]) and then get the type of the key in the repository.

Comment: the best you can do (as far as I know) is enforce correctness, i.e.

`trait Repository[K, E <: Entity[K]]`

Answer (score -1):

Just out of the top of my mind, you can use **Any** instead of **Long** and then you can use **case match** to convert it back to the type you need.

The following code compiles and should work but I haven't tried it yet.

```
trait Repository[E <: Entity] {
  def exists(id: Any): Boolean
  def get(id: Any): E
  def insert(entity: E): Unit
  def delete(entity: E): Unit
}

case class SimpleRepository(user: User) extends Repository[User] {

   def exists(id: Any) = {
      id match {
         case key: Long => user.id.equals( key )
         case (key: Long, key2: String) => 
            user.id.equals( key ) && user.name.equals( key2 )
         case _ => false
      }
   }

   def get(id: Any) = {
      id match {
         case key:Long => user
         case _ => user
      }
   }

  def insert(entity: User) = {

  }

  def delete(entity: User) = {

  }

}
```

Not sure about your specific use case but I hope it helps.